# Which voting system gives geographic representation while not requiring districts?

Tags: voting-systems

I'm pondering the idea of very small, local councils taking up at least part of city governance. My city is already divided into boroughs of average 10 000 people. There seem to be little point in drawing further electoral districts within the borough, since they would literally consist of single buildings. At the same time, the main issues decided in such councils would be largely related to where people live (small infrastructure, garbage management etc.), not who they are (in terms of political or ethnic identity).

Which voting system would ensure geographic representation, while possibly remaining simple to understand and requiring no further electoral districts?

Comment: IMHO these kind of questions are better off at our sister site [worldbuilding.se].

Comment: @Glorfindel: This is not about building a fictional world altogether, so I don’t see how it would be on-topic on Worldbuilding. On the other hand, election systems are very much on-topic here.

Comment: I think the answer is no, but it might depend on what you mean by geographic representation.

Comment: I believe here's the best definition: http://aceproject.org/ace-en/topics/es/esa/esa01

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Two types:

- In the United States, "Homeowners' Associations" (HOAs) are pseudo-governments that administer "small infrastructure, garbage management, etc."  These associations typically govern single buildings, or housing tract(s) established by a single developer.  HOA votes are often weighted by a proxy for the value of the homes.  In some cases, a condominium's HOA governs only a portion of a building.
- In California, certain pseudo-elections require a majority of the property owners to agree (and/or the owners of a majority of the property to agree) on an action.  The establishment of a small city involves such a pseudo-election.

Answer (score -1):

How about random ballot?

You could block out the ballots so they are distributed geographically(e.g. ballots number 1-2500 go to the south, 2501-5000 go to the east, etc.), and then you draw a random ballot from each block ensuring geographic representation without drawing district lines.

Comment: Wouldn't the geographical distribution blocks effectively be districts though?